# C++ Win32_PhysicalMedia MediaType

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wmi, wmi-query

im using visual c++ and im trying to get the serial number of hdd using wmi

here's part of my code :

```
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << "HDD SN : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);
```

It's working normally but if i have removable media it's showing them too.SO i tried to add MediaType but didnt work this is the code :

```
bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia where MediaType=29"),
```

It's not showing any results :/ please help !! and i dont want to use win32_diskdrive

Comment: Looks like Win32_PhysicalMedia only sets the Tag and SerialNumber. Everything else is NULL. Why don't you want to use Win32_DiskDrive? You can use the TAG to distinguish between PHYSICALDRIVE/CDROM/TAPE/FLOPPY/other - is that enough, or do you need to distinguish between fixed & removable media within one of these categories (e.g., PHYSICALDRIVE)?

Comment: I don't want to use Win32_DiskDrive because it doesn't work on Windows XP :/ and i need to differentiate between fixed and removable media             Any Ideas ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - as I said, the provider is only setting two properties, Tag and SerialNumber. If you can't tell the difference using those properties, PhysicalMedia won't be enough. Are you sure Win32_DiskDrive doesn't work on Windows XP? MSDN says XP is the minimum supported client.